# Deploy Flask Rest API on Nginx

Tags: python, rest, nginx, flask

Could anyone help me with this? I'm trying to deploy my python flask rest api on nginx but it's not working. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) but to be honest I'm not sure if this is what I need to do (I've already done it and still it doesn't work).

This is the code for my api:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, url_for, redirect, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)

class CreateUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return jsonify({
            'status': 'ok', 
            'message': 'user successfuly created'
        })

api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And the VH config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/apirest/apirest.sock;
    }
}
```

I'm using Postman Chrome App and each time I do a POST request to "api.domain.com/CreateUser" I get a 404 error:

```
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Add the code where you define your `route`.

Comment: First test it without nginx, see if it works from flask or not.

Comment: Yes @TarunLalwani it works perfectly in my local XAMPP.

Comment: Post nginx logs also it will have something in errors log

Comment: Also try changing `proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/apirest/apirest.sock;` to `proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/apirest/apirest.sock:/;`

Comment: @0decimal0 He use `flask-restful`. There is no need for `route`.

Comment: Post your complete nginx config